# Basic OOPs related query

Tags: c#

I have a basic doubt, I guess something which might be very common while programming in C#.

Basically here is a depiction of how my current code is structured:

**File:** api.cs

```
namespace API
{
    class OutputClass{
        private int var1;
        private int var2;
        int getVar1()
        {
            return var1;
        }
        int getVar2()
        {
            return var2;
        }
    }

    class APICore {
        public event Action<OutputClass> FrameDecodeComplete;
        void someFunction() {
            OutputClass myOutput;

            myOutput.var1 = 1;    
            myOutput.var2 = 2;

            FrameDecodeComplete(myOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

My requirement is that the user of this API creates an object of type APICore, and receives the output in the form of OutputClass object.

Obviously the lines `myOutput.var1 = 1;` and `myOutput.var2 = 2;` will throw an error because of it's protection level.

But I also need to ensure that user of the API is unable to set values for var1, var2. So I do not want to change the access level of var1 and var2 to public. And neither do I want to define functions such as setVar1(), setVar2().

Kindly comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want external assemblies to be able to access your variable, than you can use the internal keyword.

```
class OutputClass
{
    public int Var1 { get; internal set; }
}
```

---

---

That syntax is a **property**, which is a syntax that you can use to make getters and setters for your field.

The syntax i showed you is a shorthand for the following

```
class OutputClass
{    
    private int _var1;
    public int Var1 
    {
        get
        {
            return _var1;
        }
        internal set
        {
            _var1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got to learn a new concept from my answer. But it is "internal" which solves my issue completely. I did not want user to access the variable "var1" at all, rather access it via a method.

Comment: Btw, How do I use this method if var1 is a user-defined variable type (like Windows.Foundation.Size). I want to be able to access it from user side by writing `OutputClassObject.Var1.width`. But it appears that I get the following error - `cannot modify the value of Var1 since it is not a variable`

Comment: @vishal In that case you might want to make it `readonly` once the value is set in the API the user won't be able to modify it but they can still access it.

Comment: Actually readonly would not allow APICore to read the value. Anyways. I solved it via another methodology. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, how can I ensure that a new OutputClass object can be created only inside the same file, and not from the user. The user should be able to only reference to an already existing OutputClass...

Comment: @vishal in the second code block You can see how the getters and setters of the properties are actually methods.  You can put logic in there just like any other method.

Comment: @vishal I'm not a complete expert on proper use of the `internal` keyword, but you might want to give your `OutputClass` class an `internal` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

check [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword, looks like it solve you problem

but you can also add internal constructor method to you OutputClass with 2 arguments, so someFunction will call constructor and return object, in your constructor you will be able to init private variables

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like their protection level should be `internal`. That way, `var1` and `var2` will only be visible inside the assembly they are declared in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to have access to `get` properties, but not to `set` them, then you can create accessor properties like this.

```
public int var1 { get; private set; }
```

That way you can modify the variable yourself from within your class, and consumers of the class can access the value, but can't change it.

Comment: That doesn't help `APICore` access `var1` in `OutputClass`.

Comment: I'm not following. Can you explain? If var1 is a public property with an implicit getter, then APICore can access it from the instance.

Comment: `APICore` can't **set** `var1`, which was the question the OP posed.

Comment: From the question: "I also need to ensure that user of the API is unable to set values for var1, var2."

Comment: Read the question again: "Obviously the lines myOutput.var1 = 1; and myOutput.var2 = 2; will throw an error because of it's protection level.". The OP wants `APICore` to be able to set `var1` and `var2` when it creates `OutputClass`, but not have the calling code that receives the `OutputClass` from `APICore` be able to change `var1` and `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

Give `OutputClass` a protected constructor that takes parameters to set `var1` and `var2` then give `APICore` a private nested class that derives from `OutputClass` and passes parameters to the protected base constructor.

Something like:

```
class OutputClass{
    private int var1;
    private int var2;
    int getVar1()
    {
        return var1;
    }
    int getVar2()
    {
        return var2;
    }

    protected OutputClass(int _var1, int _var2)
    {
        var1 = _var1;
        var2 = _var2;
    }
}

class APICore {
    public event Action<OutputClass> FrameDecodeComplete;
    void someFunction() {
        SubOutputClass myOutput = new SubOutputClass(1,2);

        FrameDecodeComplete(myOutput);
    }

    private SubOutputClass : OutputClass
    {
        public SubOutputClass(int var1, int var2) : base(var1, var2)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

With `internal` any class in the *same assembly* will be able to access it. Which may or may not be a problem for you.