# Class creatable only within same file, other users can only reference it

Tags: c#

This question is a continuation of the following question:
[Basic OOPs related query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436181/basic-oops-related-query/19436266?noredirect=1#comment28818303_19436266)

How can I ensure that `OutputClass` object can be created only inside the same file (api.cs), i.e.

```
OutputClass object1 = new ObjectClass(3);
```

Whereas the user of the API should not be able to create a new storage for this class, rather only be able to reference to it when it is provided from the API, i.e. the user of API should be able to do only the following:

```
OutputClass object1
```

whereas if he tries to create a new ObjectClass, it should not be possible.

Comment: Please see [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) for C#.  I am guessing you are looking for `protected`, `internal` or `protected internal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the constructor `internal`  or `private`:

```
public class OutputClass
{
    internal OutputClass()
    {
    }
}
```

`internal` means that it can be called from any class *in the same assembly* (not just the .CS file).  `private` means that it can only be called from within that class (usually through a static factory method).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the constructor of `OutputClass` as `private`, assuming there is some mechanism within that class to create an instance.  Otherwise an `internal` modifier might be more appropriate.

```
class OutputClass
{
    private OutputClass()
    {
        // inaccessible to anything but OutputClass methods
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey. This won't work since getOutputClass() can be called from the user of the API. The answer by D Stanley works well. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I thought you were after a way of controlling a user constructing the object, but having re-read your question I realise you're not.